# Agrupar y mostrar promedios de una subconsulta que utiliza union

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla con los siguientes datos..

```
INSERT INTO Partido (nro,cod_local,gol_local,cod_visitante,gol_visitante)
VALUES              (1,  'AR',     2,        'CL',         1),
                    (2,  'US',     0,        'CO',         2),
                    (3,  'BR',     7,        'HA',         1),
                    (4,  'MX',     1,        'VE',         1),
                    (5,  'PA',     0,        'AR',         2),
                    (6,  'PE',     0,        'BR',         8),
                    (7,  'CO',     1,        'PR',         0),
                    (8,  'AR',     1,        'VE',         0),
                    (9,  'BR',     1,        'AR',         1),
                    (10, 'MX',     0,        'CR',         0);
```

Lo que intento hacer es obtener el promedio de gol por partido por cada equipo. Por ejemplo, Argentina tiene 6 goles en 4 partidos (1,5).

En esta consulta se ven los goles marcados por cada equipo

```
SELECT tot.cod_local,tot.cantGoles
FROM
(
    SELECT cod_local,gol_local AS cantGoles
    FROM Partido 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cod_visitante,gol_visitante AS cantGoles
    FROM Partido
) AS tot;
```

El problema es que esa consulta no me muestra los datos agrupados (me los da separado por partido). Siguiendo el ejemplo de Argentina, en los resultados de este país me sale algo como..

```
Pais      Goles
AR        2
AR        1
AR        1
AR        2
```

Cuando quisiera que salga..

```
Pais      Goles
AR        6
BR        16
(etcetera)
```

Como no se agruparlo (intente por tot.cod_local pero no me da bien los valores) no se como seguir para terminar obteniendo el promedio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si deben agruparse para obtener el promedio por cada país, sería así:

```
select tot.codigo_pais, avg (tot.goles)
from (
         select cod_local as codigo_pais, gol_local as goles
         from partido
         union all
         select cod_visitante as codigo_pais, gol_visitante as goles
         from partido
     ) as tot
group by tot.codigo_pais
```